# Extract info from filename

Tags: r

I wonder how I would extract the information below from the filename? The last 3 digits in the filename is the injection order. After"POS_" the sample type is presented. Any suggestions? Thanks!

```
 df <- c("2018-03-04_B6W3_RN_POS_lQC09_098.mzML", "2018-03-05_B7W3_RN_POS_LVF957364573527_108.mzML", "2018-03-06_B8W3_RN_POS_sQC09_001.mzML")
    df 
    [1] "2018-03-04_B6W3_RN_POS_lQC09_098.mzML"           "2018-03-05_B7W3_RN_POS_LVF957364573527_108.mzML"
    [3] "2018-03-06_B8W3_RN_POS_sQC09_001.mzML"
```

It should look like:

injection:

```
"098" "108" "001"
```

sample:

```
"lQC" "LVL" "sQC"
```

Comment: Use a regex with lookahead.

Comment: Something like that could do `strsplit(gsub(".*POS_(\\D+)?.*_(\\d+)?.*", "\\1 \\2", df), " ", fixed = TRUE)` though I"m not sure what's your exact desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is based on the package `stringr`and positive lookahead in `(?=\\.)` as well as positive lookbehind in `(?<=POS_)`:

```
dt <- data.frame(injection = str_extract(df, "\\d{3}(?=\\.)"),
                 sample = str_extract(df, "(?<=POS_)\\w{3}"))
dt
  injection sample
1       098    lQC
2       108    LVF
3       001    sQC
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
require(stringr)

df <- c("2018-03-04_B6W3_RN_POS_lQC09_098.mzML", "2018-03-05_B7W3_RN_POS_LVF957364573527_108.mzML", "2018-03-06_B8W3_RN_POS_sQC09_001.mzML")
df 
# [1] "2018-03-04_B6W3_RN_POS_lQC09_098.mzML"           "2018-03-05_B7W3_RN_POS_LVF957364573527_108.mzML"
# [3] "2018-03-06_B8W3_RN_POS_sQC09_001.mzML" 

injection_str <- str_extract(df, "[0-9]{3}(?=\\.)")

injection_str

# [1] "098" "108" "001"

sample_str <- str_extract(df, "(?<=(POS_))[a-zA-Z0-9]{3}")

sample_str

# [1] "lQC" "LVF" "sQC"
```